# More speed for BigQuery data in Shiny

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, google-bigquery

I don't like to access a complete public BigQuery dataset in my case `geo_us_boundaries`. But I'd like to choose the data by `state` using  the query `glue::glue_sql("SELECT * FROM states WHERE state = {x}", x = input$selectedvariable1, .con=bq_con)`. I try to do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(bigrquery)
library(DBI)
library(sf)
library(glue)

# Open a public BigQuery dataset eg. "geo_us_boundaries"
bq_con <- dbConnect(
  bigrquery::bigquery(),
  project = "bigquery-public-data",
  dataset = "geo_us_boundaries",
  billing = "my-project"
)
bigrquery::dbListTables(bq_con) # List all the tables in BigQuery data set


# Take the table
dataset <- dplyr::tbl(bq_con, 
                      "states") # connects to a table


# Enumerate the states
dataset_vars <- dataset %>% dplyr::distinct(geo_id, state, state_name)%>% 
  collect() 
str(dataset_vars)


# Create the shiny dash
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title="States Dashboard"),  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable0",
                  label = "Geo ID", 
                  choices = c(unique(dataset_vars$geo_id)),selected = TRUE ), 
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable1",
                  label = "State", 
                  choices = c(unique(dataset_vars$state)),selected = TRUE ), 
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable2",
                  label = "State name", 
                  choices = c(unique(dataset_vars$state_name)),selected = TRUE )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        splitLayout(plotOutput("myplot")))
      
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output){
  
  # # Selection of variables for plots constructions
  
  sqlInput <- reactive({
    glue::glue_sql("SELECT * FROM states WHERE state = {x}", x = input$selectedvariable1, .con=bq_con)
  })
  stands_sel <- function() dbGetQuery(bq_con, as.character(sqlInput()), stringsAsFactors = T)
  
  print(sqlInput)

  observe({
    
    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
      
      #Create the plot 
      stands_sel_sf <- st_as_sf(stands_sel(), wkt = "state_geom", crs = 4326) 
      ggplot() + geom_sf(data=stands_sel_sf) }) 
  }) #end of observe function.
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
#
```

But this type of data access by `state` selection is very slow and in my real-world problem I have big geometries and I spend several minutes for downloading from BQ and for plots finished too. There is some approach for increasing the speed of this operation?

Please any help with it?

Thank in advance!

Comment: More an idea than a solution. The data needs to be downloaded and the format is JSON. Is there a need for two or more digit precision? If not, you could try to truncate the digit in BigQuery by:   SELECT 
state,
area_land_meters,
SAFE.ST_GeogFromText((REGEXP_REPLACE(ST_ASTEXT(state_geom), r"\.(\d)\d+", r".\1")), make_valid => TRUE)
from
`bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.states`

Comment: Thanks @Samuel, but unfortunately in my real problem I have geometries with more than two digits and attributes information too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the time spent downloading the data, and not e.g. rendering it? The query takes couple seconds, and even the largest state by geometry text size (Texas) is only 1.3 MB. This should not take that minutes to download.

Anyway, a typical solution is to simplify the state geometry:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(state_geom), ST_Simplify(state_geom, 1000) AS state_geom 
FROM states WHERE state = {x}
```

This makes the heaviest state (now Alaska) is under 40KB size, and should be quicker to download and to draw.

Note that this performs `ST_Simplify` computation every time in the query, which is somewhat expensive. You'd probably want to do it only once - create table with simplified state geometry and read from it instead - this makes query itself much cheaper and faster too, as the query reads less data, and does not have to compute simplified geometry.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp.states AS
SELECT * EXCEPT(state_geom), ST_Simplify(state_geom, 1000) AS state_geom
FROM  `bigquery-public-data`.geo_us_boundaries.states;
```